# Capturing image with html2canvas

Tags: html2canvas

I am trying to capture a div into an image using html2canvas.
I have a div with scrollbars.I want to convert this div element to image. When running html2canvas, it only captures the visible portion of the screen, truncating everything hidden from the scroll. Setting the height ,width attribute has no impact.I am using html2canvas version 0.4.1.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to move the DIV, for which you want to capture the image, upwards, it may capture the entire image. I faced similar issue and then resolved the issue by adjusting the CSS. Adjusting the height attribute either in html2canvas or in CSS sometimes helps.